# call staic method with instance class (LocalDate

Tags: java, java-8, localdate

my question is about the class `LocalDate` have a static method of that return a new instance of the classe example

```
LocalDate local = LocalDate.of(2019,9,21);
```

the probleme is that i can't call the method of with instance class `localDate
(local.of(..) !!!!!!!!!???)`

thanks for help :)

Comment: do you have any problem in doing that? i don't have any problem in doing that?

Comment: thanks @Deadpool the probleme is intellij autocomplete not suggest to me the methode of() because of sonar probleme (While it is possible to access static members from a class instance, it's bad form, and considered by most to be misleading because it implies to the readers of your code that there's an instance of the member per class instance.) but it work

Answer (score 1):

The static method  LocalDate of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) Obtains an instance of LocalDate from a year, month and day. so you must use a reference of a LocalDate object to store the returned instance.

LocalDate local = LocalDate.of(2019,9,21);

Comment: thanks @Rajitha but I m not understand your answer my Question is why I can' t do that LocalDate local = LocalDate.of(2019,9,21); local.of(2019,9,8) with (local is object of LocalDate so I can call the staic methos)

Comment: simply how I can explain is there is no reference type call "javaLocalDate" so you will anyway get a compilation error

Comment: sorry but I know there is no reference type call "javaLocalDate" it's my error but I my code is with  LocalDate :)